# Permission Error when installing pygame on python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When I install `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl` for python 3.5 I get a permission error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

and then it says the error is in a site package of pygame.

Comment: most likely installed Python 3.5 in Program Files or some other place that requires administrator priviledges. Run the installer as administrator or run the console/pip as administrator.

Comment: The first thing I did was to run the command as an administrator, but I will try moving python 3.5 to outside of Program files.

Comment: And now I get a fatal error in the launcher: Unable to create process with '"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by reinstalling python outside the program files.