# Install pygame on window10 cmd error

Tags: exception, cmd, pygame, installation

I have been using Window OS and latest python version(64bit) 
I was trying to install pygame on cmd window but have problems like picture that I uploaded... 
please check and advise for me...

The error message in the cmd window:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post image links, rather write down the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what is described in this link:

[Permission Error when installing pygame on python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662746/permission-error-when-installing-pygame-on-python-3-5)

See also the comments.